# Generating random data in rails : should I use forgery / faker or ffaker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, faker, ruby-forgery

I've been using Faker for generating random data for my test and for seeding my database in rails. However, I found it a little slow for what it does.

I've heard that ffaker does the same but faster, and I have also heard of forgery. Can anyone highlight me the difference between those gems and tell me which one is the best ? New challenger are accepted...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't attest to ffaker, but I can tell you that we use forgery in our test suite with > 150 tests, and it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using both faker and forgery. Both are good for generating random data. However, forgery has more built-in dictionaries than faker. You can compare:

https://github.com/stympy/faker/tree/master/lib/faker
https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery/tree/master/lib/forgery/dictionaries

You can add your custom dictionaries to both.

But faker seems to be more popular for some reason. It has more watchers, stars and forks in github than forgery.